# How to loop between files in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop

The folder content I want to loop:

- versions (folder)

  - 1.0.0.sql
  - 1.0.1.sql
  - 1.0.2.sql
  - 1.0.3.sql
  - 1.0.4.sql
  - 1.1.0.sql
  - 1.1.1.sql

I'm taking `currentVersion` & `targetVersion` from user. I want to loop between these 2 files & write available file names. For example if `currentVersion = 1.0.1` & `targetVersion = 1.0.4`, I want to write `1.0.2`, `1.0.3`, `1.0.4` in console (target version included). Or `currentVersion = 1.0.3` & `targetVersion = 1.1.1`, I want to write `1.0.4`, `1.1.0`, `1.1.1` in console.

```bash
    #!/bin/bash

    read -p "Current Version: " currentVersion
    read -p "Target Version: " targetVersion
    
    #for loop
```

Comment: What does "loop between these 2 files" mean?

Comment: I edited the question to be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup:

```
$ mkdir versions
$ touch versions/1.0.{0..4}.sql versions/1.1.{0,1,10}.sql

$ ls -1 versions
1.0.0.sql
1.0.1.sql
1.0.2.sql
1.0.3.sql
1.0.4.sql
1.1.0.sql
1.1.1.sql
1.1.10.sql
```

General design:

- use `find` to obtain a list of filenames
- add a pair of dummy files to this list (`${currentVersion}.sql dummy`, `${targetVersion}.sql dummy`)
- perform a 'version' sort of this list via `sort -V`
- use a `while/read` loop to process the list looking for files within the desired range (**NOTE:** I'm assuming OP may want to perform some follow-on operations with the version numbers and/or associated filenames hence the use of a `bash` loop)

Results of the `find + dummies | sort -V`:

```
$ { find versions -name '*.sql'; printf '%s dummy\n' versions/1.0.3.sql versions/1.1.2.sql; } | sort -V
versions/1.0.0.sql
versions/1.0.1.sql
versions/1.0.2.sql
versions/1.0.3.sql
versions/1.0.3.sql dummy                   # start of desired range
versions/1.0.4.sql
versions/1.1.0.sql
versions/1.1.1.sql
versions/1.1.2.sql dummy                   # end of desired range
versions/1.1.10.sql
```

The complete `bash` script:

```
$ cat looper
#!/bin/bash

currentVersion="$1"
targetVersion="$2"

fstart="versions/${currentVersion}.sql"
  fend="versions/${targetVersion}.sql"

unset inrange

while read -r fname dummy
do
    if [[ "${inrange}" = 'yes' && "${dummy}" = '' ]]
    then
        fversion="${fname#*/}"                                    # strip off "versions/"
        fversion="${fversion%.*}"                                 # strip off ".sql"

        echo "do something with ${fname} and ${fversion}"
    fi

    [[ "${fname}" = "${fstart}" && "${dummy}" = 'dummy' ]] && inrange=yes
    [[ "${fname}" = "${fend}"                           ]] && break

done < <( { find versions -name '*.sql'; printf "%s dummy\n" "${fstart}" "${fend}"; } | sort -V )
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./looper 1.0.1 1.0.4
do something with versions/1.0.2.sql and 1.0.2
do something with versions/1.0.3.sql and 1.0.3
do something with versions/1.0.4.sql and 1.0.4

$ ./looper 1.0.3 1.1.2
do something with versions/1.0.4.sql and 1.0.4
do something with versions/1.1.0.sql and 1.1.0
do something with versions/1.1.1.sql and 1.1.1

$ ./looper 1.0.3 1.1.12
do something with versions/1.0.4.sql and 1.0.4
do something with versions/1.1.0.sql and 1.1.0
do something with versions/1.1.1.sql and 1.1.1
do something with versions/1.1.10.sql and 1.1.10
```

---

If OP's sole objective really is to *just* print the version numbers to the console then we can use the same `find + dummies | sort -V` to feed a more efficient `awk` script, eg:

```
$ cat looper2
#!/bin/bash

currentVersion="$1"
targetVersion="$2"

fstart="versions/${currentVersion}.sql"
  fend="versions/${targetVersion}.sql"

awk '
/ dummy/ && inrange { exit }
/ dummy/            { inrange = 1; next }
inrange             { gsub(/^.*[/]|[.]sql$/,"")     # strip off leading "versions/" and trailing ".sql"
                      print $0
                    }
' < <( { find versions -name '*.sql'; printf "%s dummy\n" "${fstart}" "${fend}"; } | sort -V )
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./looper2 1.0.1 1.0.4
1.0.2
1.0.3
1.0.4

$ ./looper2 1.0.3 1.1.2
1.0.4
1.1.0
1.1.1

$ ./looper2 1.0.3 1.1.12
1.0.4
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.1.10
```